# Display indented XML code within a HTML page

Tags: .net, html, xml, xslt

I have a programmatically created HTML document on which I would like to show some XML-**code**, fully formatted with line breaks and tabulators. That is, it should look like if you drag an xml file without a xml-stylesheet directly onto your browser (most browsers do some kind of xml-rendering with some default style sheet).

Now, I *can* of course escape all the characters (like `<>`, tab and newline) and do the indenting myself (using css styles, for example), but I was wondering whether I couldn't re-use some 'default' xml-stylesheet from somewhere. Preferrably also one that has some javascript node-folding, too.

Do you know such a stylesheet/xslt? Or would you suggest another way to achieve this?

I'm using C#.

PS: I tried to use the XmlNotepad.DefaultSS.xslt from Microsoft's XmlNotepad, but I couldn't really get that working. :T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a SyntaxHighlighter .. like [this one](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) - it has an XML brush - [example of XML here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/xml.html)

All you need to do is wrap your XML in `<pre>` tags and the rest is done for you - indentation, line numbers etc...

Comment: Hmm.. true, actually, the <pre> tag was pretty much what I needed. On the other hand, a pretty print XSLT would be nice, since now I have to reformat the XML code correctly before embedding it into the HTML. And I fear that I'm going to be asked to provide code folding too.. :S